# Xcode crashes repeatedly on both 7.2.1 and 7.1.1 versions

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed Xcode 7.2.1 and it crashes every time I try to type some code, then a box titled "**Xcode quite unexpectedly**" containing details appears. I uploaded the whole details here:

http://pastebin.com/KZCRntiT

I also installed and older version of Xcode (7.1.1) to see if the problem is due to the version or not, and found that the older version also keeps crashing every time I write some code.

This is not the case for a specific project, it crashes on both current and new projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer doesn't solve your problems, delete the file of `~/Library/Cache/com.apple.dt.Xcode` and nuke in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` at least `DerivedData` if not the rest of the files as well. Have Xcode closed when you do it.

Comment: I removed `com.apple.dt.Xcode` and all the files/folders in `Developer/Xcode/` and ran the Xcode again. Nothing was changed and it kept crashing.

Comment: Your best bet at this point is then probably to nuke your computer from orbit (*backup* all files, fresh install OS X) - it'll be faster than searching for arcane solutions to Xcode's quirks, unfortunately. IF this is occurring with fresh projects.

Comment: It's less than a week that I formatted my mac and installed El Capitan. I'm doubtful if reinstalling the OS could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I unplugged all of my devices, opened XCode, and close all tabs individually. I think there was an issue with one of my tabs. Everything is working now.